# Can't connect locally with IP but 4G device can connect with IP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ubuntu, apache2

Any ideas as for the cause of this?

I have a NUC webserver running Ubuntu, and a workstation with Windows 10, both computers can't connect to the webserver when using my public IP. They can connect fine using the webservers internal IP.

However my phone using 4G can connect fine using my public IP.

Comment: Are you sure the IP address on the WAN port of your router _is_ the IP address on the internet? Have you configured NAT on your router?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out my router does not support NAT loopback. Thanks @Aetherus